# Write values while runnig program

Tags: java

i want to write some data to a .txt file.

```
     public void writeToFile(String filename) {

    try {

        //Construct the BufferedWriter object
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

        //Start writing to the output stream
        bufferedWriter.write("first value : " + firstValue);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //Close the BufferedWriter
        try {

           if (bufferedWriter != null) {
               bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

i use this code, buth the problem is, that it overwrites the first line constantly (i think).
Does anyone have a idea how i can fix this?
i read everey 50ms a value from the serial port, and wan't to write this. (every value on a separate line)

it should write the values until i close the progam.

best regards

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the line:

```
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
```

To:

```
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true));
```

I will open the FileWrite in Append mode, it is, it will add content in the file, and not overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

Open the writer like this:

```
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true));
```

That should open the file for appending. See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29).